# Using jquery Uniform plugin with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, jquery-uniform

I am using the following AngularJS directive to integrate [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com) jQuery plugin with angularjs

```
myApp.directive('pluginUniform', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.show().uniform();
            if (!element.parents(".checker").length) {
                element.show().uniform();
            }

        }
    };
});
```

The issue I am having is that it does not show checked for `ng-checked="true"` values. But when I remove the `plugin-uniform` attribute it shows the correct result.

For example, the value `$scope.isEmailChecked = true;` is set in the controller, but the following code `ng-checked="isEmailChecked"` does not show the checked checkbox.

```
<div class="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" plugin-uniform ng-model="isEmailChecked" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-checked="isEmailChecked">
        I agree 
    </label>
</div>
```

Could somebody help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
window.onload = function(){       
    // initiate layout and plugins
    ...
    setTimeout(function(){ $.uniform.update(); }, 300);
};
```